# HTML and AJAX response

Tags: html, ajax

I am working on below given scenario

1) I have html page A with input= text

2) Based on selection I am invoking ajax i.e. html page B to get data from MySQL

3) I am placing this data inform of table on page A in one of the

4) Now I have certain buttons defined on page B for update/save etc

5) When page B is sending data to page A these buttons are not working

I believe this is happeing as buttons are defined on page B so not working on page A.
Hope I am clear on my question, is there any way to resolve this.

Comment: Add your code to be more clear...

Comment: we are not able to tell you anything without your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a javascript framework thats simple to use in order to make it easier to learn javascript.

1. read input text

http://api.jquery.com/val/

1. retrieve data from Ajax

http://api.jquery.com/val/

1. [2]
2. Disable active button

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

1. Enable/disable buttons

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

would agree with above comments,
a small tip, put the JS-code for buttons generated by page B with `.live()` as the run-time generated buttons need `.live()` instead of `.click()`

for example :

```
$( "xxxx" ).live( "click", function() {...
```

Comment: The .live() method is deprecated. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in preference to .live().